# Which project depends on a certain jar on gitlab?

Tags: git, maven, gitlab

Suppose I have written an API and push it into gitlab.

```
    <groupId>com.example.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

How could I find other projects which are depend on `bar-api`?
What if I need to know the version of `bar-api` they are using?